# I don't understand why PdfReader.ComputeUserPassword() is returning null

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I am trying to receive the user's password from a PDF file. For testing purposes I'm given both, the master's and user's password. Right now I am passing the master's password in a parameter and use it to create a new instance of `iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader` which works fine. Then I'm entering an if-clause which should return whether the PDF is being opened with full permissions or not. Inside this if-clause I request the user's password by calling `iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader.ComputeUserPassword()` which returns `null`.

---

My entire code looks like this (`GetByteAr(string s)` returns the password converted to a byte array):

```
public static bool IsPasswordProtectedOwner(string pdf, string ownerPw)
{

    try
    {
        var reader = new PdfReader(pdf, GetByteAr(ownerPw));
        if (reader.IsOpenedWithFullPermissions)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("opened with full permissions");
            string pw = String.Empty;
            var computedPassword = reader.ComputeUserPassword();
            foreach (byte b in computedPassword)
                pw += Char.ConvertFromUtf32(b);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("not opened with full permissions");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) when (e is NullReferenceException || e is BadPasswordException)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
    }
    return true;
}
```

And my output looks like this:

```
opened with full permissions
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at PDFsV2.PDFInteractor.IsPasswordProtectedOwner(String pdf, String ownerPw) 
      in C:\Users\user\source\repos\PDFsV2\PDFsV2\PDFInteractor.cs:line 57
```

**Can you help me understand why `computedPassword` is `null`?** Why is `ComputeUserPassword` returning `null`?

### Edit, this is the reason why it returns null:

> https://api.itextpdf.com/iText5/5.5.13/
>
> public byte[] computeUserPassword()
>
> Computes user password if standard encryption handler is used with
>   Standard40, Standard128 or AES128 encryption algorithm.
>
> Returns:
>       user password, or null if not a standard encryption handler was used, **if standard encryption handler was used with AES256 encryption
>   algorithm**, or if ownerPasswordUsed wasn't use to open the document.

Comment: What is the value of `reader.IsEncrypted()` from the `Immediate Window`?

Comment: reader.IsEncrypted()
true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/kusl/itextsharp/blob/master/tags/iTextSharp_5_4_5/src/core/iTextSharp/text/pdf/PdfReader.cs#L3849 shows the implementation of `ComputeUserPassword` as:

```
public byte[] ComputeUserPassword() {
    if (!encrypted || !ownerPasswordUsed) return null;
    return decrypt.ComputeUserPassword(password);
}
```

As per that code (second line) it is possible for `ComputeUserPassword` to be `null`. As such, you need to cater for that in your code (i.e. check whether it is `null` before `foreach`ing over it).

In your case, it is likely because:

```
ownerPasswordUsed = decrypt.ReadKey(enc, password);
```

is returning `false`. This *may* indicate you have the wrong password value.

Similarly, [the docs](https://api.itextpdf.com/iText7/7.1.1/com/itextpdf/kernel/pdf/PdfReader.html) state:

> user password, or null if not a standard encryption handler was used
>   or if ownerPasswordUsed wasn't use to open the document.